# Javascript array with elements that have a % at the end

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort a Javascript by Assets_%

```
    CLH.US
    Assets_% : 0.57698
    Code : "CLH"
    Country: "United States"
```

allHoldings.sort((a,b) => a.Assets_% - b.Assets_% );

This is giving me an "Expression Expected" error, which I believe is being caused by the % at the end.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: bracket notation

Comment: `a["Assets_%"]` etc

Comment: While a linked duplicate is about a *dynamic* property name, the same approach works for static property names.  A string is a string and can be used to access the property.

Answer (score -2):

`%` is a special character, so you'll need to use bracket notation.

`allHoldings.sort((a,b) => a['Assets_%'] - b['Assets_%'] );`

Comment: allHoldings.sort((a,b) => a.['Assets_%'] - b.['Assets_%'] );
allHoldings.sort((a,b) => a.["Assets_%"] - b.["Assets_%"] );

both give me "Identifier expected"

Comment: oppps, my bad with the .

Comment: now it returns:

Error: allHoldings.sort is not a function

Comment: That means that `allHoldings` isn't an array.

Comment: Not my downvote, but answers to duplicates aren't helpful and not helpful answer should be downvoted.